# Django Rest-framework M2M connection serialization with through table

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've got the following tables:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class Human(models.Model):
    _id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pfpHuman", default="placeholderHuman.png")
    skills = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class Company(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Companies"

    _id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pfpCompany", default="placeholderCompany.png")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Job(models.Model):
    _id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    preferred_skills = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    connections = models.ManyToManyField('Human', through="Connection", related_name = 'job_human')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} - {self.company.name}'

class Connection(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='company_to_job')
    human = models.ForeignKey(Human, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='human_to_job')
    did_human_accept = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    did_job_accept = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

as you can see, I've tried to create a many-to-many connection for Job-Human interaction

after a few posts searches, google, youtube and a bunch more i've reached the following serializers:

```
class HumanSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = '__all__'


class CompanySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = "__all__"


class ConnectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Connection
        fields = '__all__'
        
class JobSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    human = HumanSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # connections = ConnectionSerializer(source = 'connection_set',many = True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

which are fairly simple
now when I try to make a call to the server, I get the JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "testJob",
    "preferred_skills": {
      "skills": "python"
    },
    "company": {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "testcomp",
      "image": "/images/placeholderCompany.png",
      "user": 2
    },
    "connections": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "user",
        "image": "/images/placeholderHuman.png",
        "skills": {},
        "is_active": true,
        "user": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

inside the connections[] all I get is the human serialized, without the added data like `did_human_accept` and such

expected output should have something like:

```
"connections": [
    {
      (human serialized),
      (company serialized),
      "did_human_accept" : 0,
      "did_job_accept": 0,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

answer found!
the relation inside "connections" is from the Job straight to the Human
if i want a fully serialized connection i need to call for the forgeinKey related_name

`company_to_job = ConnectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`

```
class JobSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    human = HumanSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    company_to_job = ConnectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```